# "Open in PuTTY" command of WinSCP: Can I scp files from Linux back to Windows from terminal in opened PuTTY instance?

Tags: terminal, putty, scp, winscp

I use the command "Open in PuTTY" in WinSCP. A PuTTY window pops up, but I cannot find a way to scp files from Linux back to Windows using terminal command line in PuTTY. Do you guys think this is possible?

Comment: Well, you are in WinSCP. Why don't you download the using WinSCP? Please explain.

Comment: it is faster to do everything by command line on putty than going back from putty tu winscp in order to copy files.Otherwise what is the option "open in putty" for?

Comment: *Open in PuTTY* is to get you full terminal/shell to run commands. Not to transfer files.

Answer (score 2):

From you comment, it looks like that you actually mean terminal or shell by "putty command line". From remote shell you cannot transfer files back to your local Windows machine, unless you are running a server there too. Like SSH/SFTP server, e.g. OpenSSH.

Comment: Yep I meant the putty shell. I thought opening putty from WinSCP allowed one to transfer files from the putty shell.

Comment: No, it does not.