# Transfer file via SSH from server back to client

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, putty

I am logged to remote server via ssh (linux) or via putty(windows). I want to copy file back to my origin machine from remote bash prompt (because of convenience). I know I can launch FileZilla or WinSCP at my machine and copy files, but I would like to know how to do that from remote bash prompt.

I know I can copy files via pscp using another ssh link:

```
pscp server.file localuser@local:/local_path
```

But this is impossible to use if client does not run a openssh server.

I see that my server has some variables like SSH_CLIENT, SSH_CONNECTION etc. Is it possible to use this information to craft a command like this?

```
copy_from_server server.file local.file
```

Where server.file is file located on the server (local to bash prompt where copy_from_server runs) and local.file is destination on client machine where file should be copied.

I would like a solution that works for windows and linux but I am also open to solutions that work on linux only or on windows only.

**EDIT:**
Similar questions:

- ["Open in PuTTY" command of WinSCP: Can I scp files from Linux back to Windows from terminal in opened PuTTY instance?](https://superuser.com/questions/590836/open-in-putty-command-of-winscp-can-i-scp-files-from-linux-back-to-windows-fr)

Comment: No, that can't be done. Also, this is a duplicate of the link you give, and the answer there is also "no".

Comment: It cannot be done without additional software I guess. Now, I am tinkering with method of tunneling rsync port to remote server and to use rsync to copy files. I hope it will be possible with little configuration to accomplish that.

Comment: While this could be done using a *nix client using the command line SSH program, it can't be done with Putty.  `tar -cf - /some/file | ssh host.name tar -xf - -C /destination` would be how to do that.  Note that for a variety of reasons, it's usually better to just use software more suited to the task, but it will work in a pinch.

Answer (score 3):

While in your `ssh` session (not `PuTTY`), press <kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>~</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to enter a command line on your local machine.

At the shell you can run a command by prefixing it with `!`:

```
$ ssh> !scp <user@server:file> <local path>
```

Once the file has been copied the command prompt will exit and you'll be returned to your `ssh` session without the need to re-enter your credentials.

You'll need `PermitLocalCommand=yes` in `/etc/ssh_config` (client) for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use rsync for this. Look for examples of rsync command on the internet.
Here is an example:

rsync -av -e ssh /var/www/your-site.com/ VPS_IP:/var/www/your-site.com/

I found this by reading about a Wordpress migration at: 
http://bit.ly/1pGp5cw